# Most pythonic way to get one item from a list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say I have a list of dicts where `dict['id']` is unique, and I want to access one specific dict.

This is how I would usually do that, more or less.

```
d_ = [d for d in list_of_dicts where d['id']=='the_id_i_want'][0]
```

Is there a better/cleaner/more pythonic way to do this?

This is an API response, otherwise I'd just make it a dict in the first place.

Comment: Or maintain an additional dict mapping id to the list of dicts.

Comment: If each dict in the list contains uinque ids, why not combine them into a single dict

Comment: Use a regular `for` loop and break out of the loop when you find the matching dict.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or is it done often with the same data? If often, the cost of indexing the list would be worth it.

Comment: Just use a regular for loop and break out early. For loops are perfectly pythonic

Answer (score 3):

Just use an ordinary `for` loop. Then you can stop the loop when you find the one you want. The list comprehension will keep looping unnecessarily.

```
d_ = None
for d in list_of_dicts:
    if d['id'] == 'the_id_i_want':
        d_ = d
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) (Note: you can use `default=` parameter to specify value to return when dict is not found):

```py
list_of_dicts = [{"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 1}]

d = next(d for d in list_of_dicts if d["id"] == 1)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```py
{'id': 1}
```

---

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid looping over the entire list using a generator to take just the leading value:

```
d = next( 
    (d for d in list_of_dicts if d['id'] == 'the_id_i_want'), 
    None)
```

Here, if it is not found, `d` will be set to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `dict` with indices of the unique `id`, then use that to select the `dict` you want

```
d = [{"id": 1, "val": 2}, {"id": 2, "val": 2}]
inds = {x["id"]: i for i, x in enumerate(d)}

# if you want dict with id equal to 1
d[inds[1]]
# {'id': 1, 'val': 2}
```